# Why are warnings CS0108 & CS0114 *NOT* errors by default in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

Warning CS0108 trips when a variable is declared with the same name as a variable in a base class.
Warning CS0114 is the equivalent for methods.

Both flag up as a warning but not an error.  Compilation continues and the executable can be run.

But the risk is a logic error or bug where the wrong one is invoked.

**This is extremely dangerous in live production environments.**

**It's also very "non-obvious" when debugging: the code looks like it's doing the right thing when stepped through but is not.  The bug can take forever to identify in heavily abstracted/inherited code-bases.**

Surely the "new" keyword exists for a reason and (even more surely) usage should be enforced by a compile error - not just a warning.

But this is not so.  You have to set it up by hand on each project in a solution; it's not even possible to enforce solution-wide.

And I haven't yet found a way to make this the default behaviour for new solutions.

Why?

Comment: `But the risk is a logic error or bug where the wrong one is invoked.` A _risk_ is not necessarily the same as an error. Hence why warning rather than error. Plus, once you define it as a warning then _by definition_ you have stated it is acceptable. If they changed it to errors by default (for all customers) code that _used_ to compile would stop compiling.

Comment: Different from many many other warnings (if you dont start cleaning up early on, projects quickly reach 1000s of warnings) those are the warnings that have consistently produced mal-behaviour, at least for me and in the current project. Today I hit it for the nth time and decided to google-stackoverflow-solve it - and i am happy now to have removed another source of untold error and pain in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually set the warnings to be errors solution wide (kind of). Only restriction is that the solution has to be in the top level directory.

You can add a Directory.Build.targets file next to your solution to set up the warnings to be treated as errors. This file will automagically be loaded and used in the build process (see more in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets)

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WarningsAsErrors>$(WarningsAsErrors);CS0108;CS0114</WarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

As for why it is by default a warning and not an error (my thoughts): errors are things that break the build and you can't compile the project/solution, while warnings are to warn the user about a potential mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio by default considers as an error everything that makes a program unable to compile. Since these considerations do not affect the compilation but only the quality of the code, they are considered warnings. But as Styxxy has pointed out, you can treat any warning you like as an error.

Comment: Oh sure, I get all this.  But there is an inconsistency: the `new` and `override` keywords are in the C# language for a reason; it seems strange that the compiler doesn't enforce proper usage.  I would therefore argue that their absence should cause a compilation error.  In any case, I can foresee no useful circumstance where you would want this ambiguity to exist.  Accepted, introducing it now might break old code - but who wouldn't want this fixing?

Answer (score 0):

The common understanding of what the difference is between warnings and errors is that with an error, you have to fix it before you can proceed, whereas with a warning, you can just ignore it and proceed.

This understanding is technically correct, in the sense that this is in fact how most compilers behave, but the reasoning behind this compiler behavior, and therefore the reasoning behind this whole understanding, is wrong. It has been wrong since the dawn of the software industry, and it continues to be wrong today. The magnitude of the wrongness, multiplied by the pervasiveness of the wrongness, is truly staggering.

The difference **should be** that you can suppress a warning whereas you cannot suppress an error; however, you should absolutely have to deal with both of them, meaning that you should absolutely have to deal with all warnings before being allowed to proceed, either by resolving them or by explicitly suppressing them.

The "treat warnings as errors" option corrects the wrong behavior of compilers, and exists precisely for the benefit of those (apparently very few) people in the industry who happen to have their reasoning right on this issue.